# How to find out all insecure pages (http) in both fronted & admin ? magento 1.9.3.4

Tags: magento2, database, magento-1

SSL is successfully installed in my website. I have installed some modules when I click the setting of those modules, In admin, urls page showing notification.

> your connection to this site is not fully secure

[image]

I want to find out all my insecure pages in frontend and admin so that i can modify them and make them secure.

Answer (score 0):

Check this website: https://www.whynopadlock.com/
The report may help to know where to fix.

Comment: this website does not show insecure pages

Comment: For the front end part it will. Here is an example: Total number of items: 397 Number of insecure items: 12 Insecure URL: http://[the path] Found in: https://[thepath]